# Haskell: Converting Float to Int (mean average)

Tags: haskell, int

I have a function which must return an Int, however I need to use a local definition to find the average of three parameters; such that:

```
avg = (a + b + c) / 3
```

However this of course returns a float, how do I convert the result into an int (or more specifically round it up or down)?

Comment: [`round`, `ceiling` or `floor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:round) ;) (or use `div` instead of `(/)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I commented you can use either [`round`, `ceiling` or `floor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:round) like this:

```
avg :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> Int
avg a b c = round $ fromIntegral (a+b+c) / 3
```

or you can use `div` instead (which will truncate towards negative infinity ...):

```
avg' :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> a
avg' a b c = (a+b+c) `div` 3
```

if you want different input types than you might have to use some other conversions too but I cannot tell from your question.

Comment: Im not quite sure how to implement either of these to my scenario, basically I want to input three int values, calculate the average of them and use guards to determine how many of the values are higher than their average (can either be two or one), and I'm using the local definition avg = (a + b + c) / 3 to try and calculate said average and use it in the guards.

Comment: sorry my bad ... you have to use `avg = round (fromIntegral (a+b+c) / 3)` in this case

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks a lot :)